# Where can you get an ADFS token signing certificate template

Tags: certificate, adfs

The topic says it all.  Had anyone generated a self signed token signing cert from a template and where can you download a template (not a tool like makecert)?  This is not the generic SSL cert, but a token signing cert.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "template"?  Do you want to generate the certificate by hand?  makecert or openssl are the usual tools used for this process, and it's probably a good idea to use them unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Makecert isn't working and I'd like to get a "regular" cert for token signing

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a template you can publish in your Windows CA so when someone needs to request an ADFS certificate they can select that template at issuance.  If so, I think this is what you are looking for:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn781428.aspx (note:  the title says just getting a certificate but the instructions walk you through setting up the template first).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a "template", but this question offers a number of ways to generate the certificate - makecert, openssl, and SelfSSL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464441/how-to-create-a-self-signed-x509-certificate-with-both-private-and-public-keys

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in my lab. It worked for me.

Made an tokencert.inf file like so.

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=Self Signed Cert"
KeyLength = 2048
ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
KeySpec = 1
KeyUsage = 0
RequestType = Cert
SMIME = False
ValidityPeriod = Years
ValidityPeriodUnits = 2
Exportable = True
```

Then used

```
certreq -new c:\temp\tokencert.inf c:\temp\tokencert.crt
```

used certmgr.msc to export from user store with private key as pfx and import to machine store. You can also export/import via Powershell etc if you prefer.

I have not tested this extensively. Feel free to post back if it fails any scenarios.